# Why is ng-include not in angular, and what is the new "angular way" of handling dynamic templates?

Tags: angular

I have been upgrading my AngularJS application to use the new Angular, and one of the things that was used extremely heavily was `ng-include`..  Situations like a modal service which allowed controllers to using the service to pass in a config that had paths to templates for the header, body, and footer of the modal:

```
<ng-include src="config.header()"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="config.body()"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="config.footer()"></ng-include>
```

I followed along this article which allowed me to basically create my own version of ng-include in modern angular:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/compiling-angular-templates-runtime-dima-slivin/

But honestly, I am so confused as to why the new angular does not have its own way to do ng-include...

Every example I have seen having to do with "dynamic templates" in modern Angular has involved `ng-template` and `ng-container` where in the context of my application (unless I am misunderstanding) the modal config would instead have templateRefs passed in and then would require a single `.html` file which would have a billion different templates like:

```
<ng-template #header-for-modal-scenario-a>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #header-for-modal-scenario-b>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #header-for-modal-scenario-c>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #body-for-modal-scenario-a>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #body-for-modal-scenario-b>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #body-for-modal-scenario-c>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #footer-for-modal-scenario-a>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #footer-for-modal-scenario-b>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #footer-for-modal-scenario-c>...</ng-template>
// etc
```

Since my app has SO many different modal header body footers (some dynamically conditionally including additional templates in them also with `ng-include`) this approach seems so incredibly dumb and horrible........  So as I am working on upgrading my app, I just am at a complete loss as to WHY `ng-include` was removed, and how is something like this supposed to be accomplished without there being a huge unwieldy `.html` file containing ALL these bazillions of template variations...  I just MUST be misunderstanding this, because there's got to be a better way to manage this in the new Angular than how I am understanding....

** EDIT **

Based off of one of the comments that knowing the answer of why `ng-include` isn't in the new Angular not being helpful--  I guess I am requesting suggestions of patterns/paradigms for the example of my modal service needing dynamic templates.  What is the "angular way" for doing this now?

Comment: How would knowing the reason help you move forward? You likely won't be pleased with the answer, which could be along the lines of "it was hard to recreate with the new framework, so we didn't"... I would take that question out.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. If your looking for a tutorial refer [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

As for your use case, if you have a dialog that needs to be opened for multiple combinations of messages. You need to create a reusable component that will accept variables such as title, description, ok, cancel. With this you can handle multiple scenarios. you can also add html in the description and render it inside the dialog.

```
dialogConfigs: Array<DialogConfig> = [{
    title: 'test',
    description: '<div> hello</div>',
    buttons: [
        { label: 'ok', callback: this.hello.bind(this) }
    ],
}];
```

html

```
<app-dialog-config [dialogConfigs]="dialogConfigs"/>
```

[innerHTML for rendering html string](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-innerhtml-examples)

Comment: the innerHTML example looked promising, but I noticed the `(click)="openWindow()"` isn't actually doing anything, it's the manual click event listener you added that is handing the window opening.  These dynamic templates need to have access to the data bindings.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular docs have a recipe for this but it requires references to any components that might be injected.

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

The latest versions of Angular support lazy loading components that you can inject into the view.

*dynamic-components.component.ts*

```
export class DynamicComponentsComponent {
  // you apply the DynamicComponentDirective to the wrapper so you can access it's viewContainer
  @ViewChild(DynamicComponentDirective, {static: true}) dynamicComponent!: DynamicComponentDirective;

  async loadComponent(name: string) {
    // first get the viewContainer reference
    const viewContainerRef = this.dynamicComponent?.viewContainerRef;

    // clear the container if it has already been loaded
    viewContainerRef?.clear();

    // lazy load the module
    const componentLoader = () => import('./greeting/greeting.module').then(module => module.GreetingModule);
    const greetingModule = await componentLoader();

    // the greeting module exposes a static embed property, which enables us to access the
    // GreetingComponent reference from the lazy loaded instance
    const greetingComponent = greetingModule.embed;

    // create the component instance in the view container
    const componentRef: {instance: any} = viewContainerRef.createComponent(greetingComponent);

    // now you can interact with the instance
    // setting input values
    componentRef.instance.name = name;
    // subscribe to output events
    componentRef.instance.replied.subscribe((reply: string) => {
      // todo do something with the reply
    })
  }

}
```

*dynamic-component.directive.ts*

```
export class DynamicComponentDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }
}
```

*dynamic-components.component*

```
<h1>Dynamic Templates</h1>

<input #name placeholder="Enter a name">
<button (click)="loadComponent(name.value)">Load Template</button>
<div class="container" appDynamicComponent></div>
```